# Присоединение к CLR (Window Forms) проекту файлов консольного приложения С++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, консоль

У меня есть 3 консольных проекта использующие много стандартных библиотек и STL.   Как добавить файлы исходного кода и заголовочные файлы в пустой проект windows forms (CLR C++) так, что б можно было, написав параметр в TextBox'e и нажав на кнопку, например, вызывать функцию сpp файла с выводом в консоль и возможно ли это вообще сделать? (Запускать .exe в форме уже пробовал, препод сказал что нельзя)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте новый проект на Managed C++, с тем чтобы результат был в DLL. Поместите весь необходимый код на C++ в него, добейтесь компиляции. Добавьте Reference на вашу DLL с C++-кодом в основной проект. Делайте вызовы из вашего основного проекта в DLL с C++-кодом.